# How to disable navigator.webdriver using Selenium in VBA?

Tags: vba, selenium, google-chrome, web-scraping, automation

So my problem is the following:
I'm trying to disable **navigator.webdriver** in Selenium VBA (Selenium Type Library) and even when I do this, it still shows the "Chrome is being controlled by automated test software" ribbon so I don't think it's working.

If anyone knows how to do it, i'd appreciate some help.

My code:

```html
Dim bot As New WebDriver
bot.AddArgument "--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled"
bot.Start "chrome"
```

Thanks!